# How do I reuse a command in bash with different parameters?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

I have two scripts that often need to be run with the same parameter:

```
$ populate.ksh 9241 && check.ksh 9241
```

When I need to change the parameter (**9241** in this example), I can go back and edit the line in history.  But since I need to change the number in two places, I sometimes make a typo.  I'd like to be able to change the parameter just once to change it in both places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bash:

```
!!:gs/9241/9243/
```

Yes, it uses `gs///`, not `s///g`. :-)

(zigdon's answer uses the last command starting with `pop`, such as `populate.sh`. My answer uses the last command, full stop. Choose which works for you.)

Comment: I don't know if it's true, but this feature seems to use more keystrokes than just editing the command line.  I used to be in love with the bang notation for recalling history, but for some reason I don't use it anymore.  Hopefully your answer will help others, however. ;-)

Comment: Think about a complex command with lots of logical operators and pipes, this one will be a life saver :)

Comment: The 'g' is not working for me.  It only replaces the first occurrence of 9241.  Is there a config option in bash that needs to be set?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the history substitution feature:

```
!pop:gs/9241/1234
```

Like so:

```
$ populate.ksh 9241 && check.ksh 9241
...
$ !pop:gs/9241/1234
populate.ksh 1234 && check.ksh 1234
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct answers have already been given, but for a more general understanding read the manpage with special attention to **"History Expansion"** and the associated shell variables (such as "`HISTCONTROL`", "`histchars`", etc.). BTW-- Your pager's search function is very useful when reading `man bash`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to simply create a wrapper script (*populate_check.ksh*) that calls the scripts in turn:

```
r=$1
populate.ksh $r && check.ksh $r
```

Or for multiple parameters:

```
for r; do
   populate.ksh $r && check.ksh $r
done
```

For tasks that are more transient, you can also parametrize the command so that it's easier to edit in history:

```
$ r=9241; populate.ksh $r && check.ksh $r
```

Or to do several at once:

```
$ for r in 9241 9242; do populate.ksh $r && check.ksh $r; done
```

Comment: Don't say "for r in $*"; prefer to say "for r" instead. The latter allows you to specify arguments with spaces or other IFS characters.

Comment: For lurkers and archives: `for r` is equivalent to `for r in "$@"`, for those unfortunate enough to use a shell not supporting the shorter form.

Comment: Excellent!  Once again, posting questions I know the answer to pays off.  Thanks.

Comment: you can also define a shell function and put it in $SHELLrc file, better than writing a yet another script file.